# voice navigation doesn't work in offline mode

Tags: google-maps

I have save the offline map for my city including surrounding areas. When I tried offline street navigation (my prepaid SIM has no data anymore), there's no voice navigation. Is this normal? Thanks alot

Comment: Is voice navigation enabled? Is your volume turned up? Sorry if this sounds dumb, but we need to know. Also, offline navigation works for me with voice.

Comment: yes to all and GPS is enabled too. I can get directions but voice navigation is not working. thanks

Comment: It works for me. Check out my devices from my profile if clarification is required